# How to run Qt application built with Necessitas on the Android emulator?

Tags: android, qt

Qt application for Android requires Ministro, but when Ministro installed (Ministro-1.0.apk, Ministro-2.0.apk or "Ministro II.apk") app tells me that ministro not found or (for "Ministro II.apk") ministro version is incompatible and need to be updated. I've download Ministro from it's official page on the sourceforge.net. Install ministro from market failed due market not allowed on emulator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed some time ago something similar, I don't know why. It is like the Ministro version which is downloaded from that website is not up to date.

Anyway, I solved by downloading the version of ministro which is provided with the market or alternatively placing the Qt libraries from the necessitas SDK in /data/local/qt in the device. You can do that in the emulator cause you have root privileges.

So, for the emulator first copy all the Qt libraries in the emulator from /Android/Qt/482/armeabi[-v7a] to /data/local/qt and start your project. Before starting it check that in Qt Creator -> Projects -> Run -> Deploy Configurations -> Use Qt libraries from device is marked and "Use local Qt libraries" is not checked.

This way it will ignore Ministro and it should use the Qt libraries you pushed.

Comment: Qt libraries - from necessitas\Android\Qt\482\armeabi[-v7a]\lib, named  libQt*.so?

Comment: You'll need more than those. You'll also need the plugins etc... Copy whatever is inside that directory (armeabi[-v7a]) at the beginning.

Comment: I need to copy folders lib, plugins, jar, imports? And destination is /data/local/qt/lib, /data/local/qt/plugins etc?

Comment: Yes. From what I remember that is what necessitas expects.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem, and this solved it:

[Idea of copying all relevant Qt dlls to device path was a bit distasteful to me ;)

1) I downloaded the Ministro II + configuration tool apk(es) from

http://files.kde.org/necessitas/installer/release/Ministro%20II.apk

2) I launched the emulator, and then used the adb in the package tools to install this apk.
[image: Command]

After this, once I start my application, Ministro pulled required Qt dlls, and I could start my application.